# How can I change rails default css after installing Foundation?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Foundation as my website's CSS framework. But I can't change the link style.

application.css.scss

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides

 */
@import "foundation_and_overrides";

* {
  font-family: "Delicious";
 }
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

`foundation_and_overrides.scss`   is default.

ALL is OK, but when I hover over a link, it's background turns black.

```
a {
    background: none;
}
```

But it did not work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I am guessing, you created a scaffold and rails generated a stylesheet specifically for that model.

There are two ways to solve that.

1. Delete the generated stylesheet
2. You can generate a scaffold without a stylesheet.

   Example:
   `rails g scaffold myModel --no-stylesheets`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks answer me and edit my question. For your answer, I delete the lib/template, no work . I don't want to restart      [rails g scaffold myModel --no-stylesheets], How can I destroy generated stylesheet.

Comment: Did you remove the styles.css?

Comment: no , only lib/template/erb/scaffold/_form.hmlt.erb, not asserts/stylesheets/application.css.

Comment: No not the application.css. You should see a file called either styles.css or style.css delete that.

Comment: Thank you very much . I got it , It work. I love you  ^_^